# What happens when we directly send tokens to Uniswap pair?

Tags: uniswap, defi, uniswapv2, liquidity

This is about Uni V2 pools.

So usually we call the function `addLiquidity` to add liquidity, but the function decides how many tokens should be added depending on the reserves.

What if we directly send the tokens? How does that not affect the price of token.

Suppose the liquidity is `1000: 1000` for two tokens, `token1`, and `token2` and suddenly I sent 10k `token2` using a normal ERC20 transfer, how does this not affect the price?

Answer (score 1):

Uniswap V2 is using the reserve amounts for calculation, not token balances.
When you send the tokens directly to the pool's address, uniswap actually does not know you are doing this, because you are interacting with the token contracts, not uniswap's contracts, i.e. updating your balance and the balance of the pool's address in the token contract.